# How can I associate a file with my app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa app "PDFHistory" on Mac OS X that uses the NSDocument architecture to save and load PDF files that are internally formatted specially for my app. I want to make it so whenever I save a file (e.g., "mydoc.pdf") from PDFHistory, then subsequently double-clicking on mydoc.pdf will automatically open it in PDFHistory.app. However, I don't want to make it so all .pdf files are automatically opened in PDFHistory, but rather use the system default (probably Preview.app). The .pdf suffix is a requirement, though, since I need the user to be able to e-mail the files to other users who can view the file in their default PDF viewer.

The problem is that if I set the LSHandlerRank to "Owner", then *all* .pdf files will be opened with PDFHistory, which is bad (since I only understand the internals of the .pdf file that PDFHistory wrote out). But if I set LSHandlerRank to "Alternate", then all .pdf files will be opened to the system default app (Preview.app), which is confusing for the user who had just created the file using my app.

Once upon a time, "creator codes" could be used to implement this sort of capability, but launch services started ignoring them back in Snow Leopard (see http://tidbits.com/article/10537). UTIs are not a substitute that provide this capability (see http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-09-22/how-not-to-use-utis).

Using Finder to get info on the file allows the user to specify a specific app to use to open the specific file. This supposedly works by setting a "usro" property in a the file's resource. There is some open-source code to mimic this behavior (https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/SetAppAffinity), but is uses deprecated functions, and so would cause Apple to reject the app from the App Store. Similarly, people have posted AppleScript to set this property (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2597365), but sandboxing would prevent me from invoking it.

Although the .pdf suffix is a requirement in order to be able to send the files to users on other systems/platforms, I considered trying to have the suffix registered with two extensions as ".phistory.pdf", which would allow "file.phistory.pdf" to be opened in PDFHistory, but "file.pdf" would be opened in the default PDF viewer. However, this simply didn't work: it appears that the final suffix is the only one used by launch services, and everything before that is ignored.

So is there any way to have my app be the default app for opening files that it created itself?